# Translate filter and nested vocabulary properties

Tags: templating, filter

Is it possible to use the translate filter in order to get nested vocabulary entries? For example having a vocabulary file like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'login'             => 'Einloggen',
    'registration'      => 'Anmeldung',
    'forms'             => [
      'email'                => 'Email',
      'password'             => 'Passwort',
    ]
];
```

I would like to get the vocabulary properties in the template in the following way:

```
<p>{{ 'forms.email' | t }}</p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not currently.  Might be worth a [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues), though?

Comment: Added thanks http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9763302-translate-filter-and-nested-vocabulary-properties