# Translation filter in Sprout Email plugin

Tags: craft3, localization, plugin-sproutemail

I would like to make a notification of Sprout Email plugin bilingual.

However, in the `body` field, the translation filter does not work.
The tag of `{{ fieldname.label|t }}` is not translated.

[image]

How is it possible to translate it?

Actually it is the same question as this, but it was asked five years ago.
[Translate filter and nested vocabulary properties](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/translate-filter-and-nested-vocabulary-properties)

Comment: Can you clarify where you are trying to translate the `{{ fieldname.label|t }}` tag? I'm not sure this is the same issue as the other question you link to as `fieldname.label` is not a nested translation, it is just a dynamic variable outputting the label to be translated.

Comment: Two quick thoughts. You may need to add a translation category to the label you are trying to translate `{{ fieldname.label|t('site') }}`. If this is on the front-end, you can take a look at Craft's Static Translations docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/sites.html#static-message-translations. If this is code in Sprout Email (which I'm not currently seeing) could you update your question and point to the code in question.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. 1) I have already tried the tag of {{ fieldname.label|t('site') }} , but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: And I added a screenshot. The tag is in the template of Sprout Email, in Craft dashboard.